# Error building Doxygen package PBuilder Launchpad

Tags: linux, ubuntu, doxygen, launchpad, pbuilder

I like to make things happen automatically. Currently I'm trying to get the latest version of Doxygen (1.8.11) working on Travis CI. At the moment I'm running version 1.7.6 on the Travis server because that's Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Precise standard version.

That version of doxygen has limitations, like markdown support for example, compared to the latest version.

I've been looking for a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=doxygen%20precise), but the latest Doxygen version I could find was 1.8.8.
So I'm currently working on creating a ppa for doxygen 1.8.11 (see my [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Evidavidorra/+archive/ubuntu/precise-backport)).
However I can build it on my own Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Precise), the build on the Launchpad server gives an error (see below) when it has almost finished building the package.

I'm new to building packages on Linux and followed (mostly) the Ubuntu Packaging Guide and the Launchpad docs. So far I could not come up with an issue. I also searched for this problem on Launchpad and have come up to the following post saying that `libpython3.4-stdlib` should be reinstalled. But honestly I've got no idea on how to do that on the Launchpad server.

Hoping anybody could explain, or point to a solution for resolving this error.

```
[ 96%] Built target _doxygen
make -f src/CMakeFiles/doxycfg.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/doxycfg.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/CMakeFiles 
[ 96%] Generating ../generated_src/configoptions.cpp
cd /«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src && /usr/bin/python /«PKGBUILDDIR»/src/configgen.py -cpp /«PKGBUILDDIR»/src/config.xml > /«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/generated_src/configoptions.cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/«PKGBUILDDIR»/src/configgen.py", line 15, in <module>
    import xml.dom.minidom
ImportError: No module named xml.dom.minidom
make[3]: *** [generated_src/configoptions.cpp] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/doxycfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/«PKGBUILDDIR»/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

Click for the [full log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/246895210/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.doxygen_1.8.11-1ppa2_BUILDING.txt.gz).

Comment: Some points to look at: 1) which version of python is the one in /usr/bin/python? 2) is the mentioned module available or has it still to be added?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Got it working by adding python (>=2.7.3) as dependency!